# Objective-C: didSelectGame method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was following this storyboard tutorial [www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2) and got into the last steps.

After I finished with all the codes I ran the simulator and clicked the add button and select one of the game.

However it doesn't automatically return to the screen, and does not change the game to the one I have checked.

Here are my codes in `gamepickerviewcontroller.m:`

```
//
//  GamePickerViewController.m
//  TabBar_Demo_2
//
//  Created by Haonan Chen on 16/7/1.
//  Copyright © 2016年 fufjvnvnf. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GamePickerViewController.h"

@interface GamePickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation GamePickerViewController{
NSArray *_games;
NSUInteger _selectedIndex;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_games = @[@"Angry Birds", @"Chess", @"Russian Roulette", @"Spin the Bottle", @"Texas Hold'em Poker", @"Tic-Tac-Toe"];
_selectedIndex = [_games indexOfObject:self.game];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return _games.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GameCell"];
cell.textLabel.text = _games[indexPath.row];

if (indexPath.row == _selectedIndex) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if (_selectedIndex != NSNotFound) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedIndex inSection:0]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

_selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

NSString *game = _games[indexPath.row];
[self.delegate gamePickerViewController:self didSelectGame:game];
}
@end
```

Comment: Before self.delegate `[self.delegate gamePickerViewController:self didSelectGame:game];` could you check `self.delegate`? What's the delegate? Are you sure its not called?

Comment: when i check an item from the list i am supposed to return to the original screen, which is what the method didselectgame is supposed to do. however i stayed at the same screen meaning that the method is not called. I also use breakpoint to confirm that the method is not called.

Comment: Is `self.delegate` nil?

Comment: no its not. i  put a breakpoint before the prepareforsegue and check self.delegate, and there is value stored in it.

Comment: but then i put a breakpoint before deselectRowAtIndexPath, and the value stored in self.delegate is 0x0; does that mean delegate is nil?

Comment: Seems to be nil. Try to `NSLog()` it, or use `po` in debugger, or check `if (self.delegate){//then call your delegate method)}`

Comment: problem fixed; forgot to name the identifier for segue